# Cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

> Let $L$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=10$. Let $L^*$ be the multiplicative group $(L\setminus\{0\}, \cdot)$ and $T(L^*)$ the torsion group of $L^*$. Prove that there are exactly four possibilities for the order of $T(L^*)$, namely $|T(L^*)|\in\{2, 4, 6, 22\}$. For each case, exhibit the extension $L$.

I thought about the extension $L=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/11})$, which satisfies $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=10$. In this case, $T(L^*)=\{e^{2\pi ki/11}\mid k \in\{0,...,10\}\}$, which are all the primitive $11^{th}$-roots of unity, so $|T(L^*)|=11\notin\{2, 4, 6, 22\}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Remember $-e^{2\pi i k/11}$ is also a root of unity in the field, so you have twice as many as you think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta_n$ be a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity generating the torsion subgroup of $L^*$. Then as $F=\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)\subseteq L$ and we know that $n$ must be even for this to be so, as if $n$ is odd, $-\zeta_n$ has twice the order, so it cannot be a generator. Write $n=2k$. Then $2k$ is the order of the torsion subgroup, and we require $\phi(2k)|10$. Now for each prime, $p|k$ we know that $\phi(2k)\ge p-1$, so the only primes which can divide $k$ are $2,3,5,7,11$ since $\phi(2k)|10$. We conclude $k=2^\alpha 3^\beta 5^\gamma 7^\delta 11^\epsilon$.

If $\epsilon >1$ then all the others are zero and we have $\epsilon=1$ by our inequalities, and $L=\Bbb Q(\zeta_{11}$. Next if $\delta, \gamma>0$ then $6|10$ or $4|10$ which is crazy so both of those are zero. If $\beta>1$ then $3|10$ and finally if $\alpha >1$ then $4|10$. So our options are

> $$\begin{cases} 0\le\alpha \le 1 \\ 0\le\beta\le 1 \\ \gamma = \delta = 0 \\ 0\le \epsilon \le 1\end{cases}$$

Which can happen? We can rule out $\alpha = \beta = 1 $ since this would give $\phi(12) = 4 | 10$, again impossible. We already covered $\epsilon >0$, so all other cases are with $\alpha, \beta$ possibly non-zero. So overall all our cases are:

> $$\begin{cases}
> \alpha = \beta = 0\iff \text{Tor }L^* = \{\pm 1\} \\
> \alpha = 1,\beta = 0 \iff \text{Tor }L^*= \{\pm i, \pm 1\} \\
> \alpha = 0, \beta = 1 \iff \text{Tor }L^* = \langle \zeta_6\rangle \\
> \epsilon = 1 \iff \text{Tor }L^* = \langle\zeta_{22}\rangle
> \end{cases}$$

And these have all the right orders to make up your candidate list. Now to find the $L$. You've already gotten the last case taken care of, what of the others?

Note that the maximal, real subfield of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{25})$ has degree ${\phi(25)/2} = 10$. Since this is totally real, the number of roots of unity is $2$, and so if $\tau$ is complex conjugation, $L=\Bbb Q(\zeta_{25})^\tau$, the fixed field of complex conjugation is such an $L$. For orders $4$ and $6$, we need an extension of $\Bbb Q(i)$ or $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$ of degree $5$. Can you see how to proceed in these cases based on how we've done things so far?

Comment: Adam, first of all, thanks for such a detailed answer. I have some questions about the steps you took. First, how do you know $T(L^*)$ has some $\zeta_n$ as a generator? Second, how did you conclude that $\phi(2k)|10$?

Comment: By the way, I've just figured out how to exhibit $L$ in each case, but I'm still struggling to understand why they are the only options

Comment: @AguirreK because of divisibility of extension degrees, you know that $[Q(\zeta_n):\Bbb Q] \Big| [L:\Bbb Q]$, and the degree of a cyclotomic extension is $\phi(n)$.

Comment: @AguirreK examples are not necessarily unique. **Any** degree $10$ totally real extension of $\Bbb Q$ has unique cyclotomic subfield $\Bbb Q$. And it's not the only one, aside from $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{25})$ you can also see that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{33})$ has $\phi(33) = 10\cdot 2=20$ has a maximal real subfield of degree $10$ over $\Bbb Q$, so that would be another such $L$.

Comment: Why is the torsion subgroup cyclic ? I think the simple way is to embed $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ into $\mathbb{C}$, so that $a \in T(L^*) \implies |a| = 1 \implies a = e^{2i \pi t}$ and say that $e^{2i \pi t} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ iff $t = k/n$

Comment: @user1952009 finite extensions of number fields have only finitely many roots of unity (by definition finite multiplicative order <=> root of 1). You don't even have to embed anything, you just write the condition $x^n=1$ is what it means to have finite order.

Comment: In my textbook it says the degree of a $n$-cyclotomic extension divides $\phi(n)$ and it is equal to $\phi(n)\Leftrightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})|\mathbb{Q})\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$. So, a prori, we can only affirm $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n}):\mathbb{Q}]|10$, but not $\phi(n)|10$. Right?

Comment: @AdamHughes do you mean that the torsion subgroup is always (locally) cyclic for any field ?

Comment: @AguirreK no, it is equal, you can exhibit $\phi(n)$ automorphisms of the field explicitly by mapping any primitive $n^{th}$ root of $1$ to another by $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^k$ with $k\in\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z^*$.

Comment: Anyway what I meant is that the answer is : $T(L^*)$ is cyclic, and $e^{2i \pi t} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ iff $t = k/n$, and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}] = \phi(n)$, and I feel weird you assume half of it at your 1st line  @AguirreK

Comment: @user1952009 no I do not, I mean that number fields always have torsion subgroups of the multiplicative group of the field which are cyclic. You don't need any embedding into $\Bbb C$ for this, this is true for any finite extension of a prime field, including positive characteristic.

Comment: @user1952009, actually I should rephrase my first question in the comments. It should be "why is $T(K^*)$ cyclic?" I agree that if that is the case, we must have $T(K^*)=<\zeta_n>$ for some $n$, but it is still not totaly clear to me why is it cyclic. Thanks!

Comment: @AguirreK because all finite order elements are roots of unity by definiton. And so all we need to show is that there are only finitely many roots of unity, but of course infintely many roots of unity would produce an infinite degree subextension, which is impossible. And if you have $\zeta_n\cdot\zeta_m$ you know its order is $lcm(m,n)$ so you have $\zeta_{lcm(m,n)}$, so you can find a single generator.